# Controlling Placement of Ellipses in Outline Mode: At End of Line or On Separate Line?

Tags: org-mode, text-editing, outline-mode, outline, fold

I have the following file opened in outline mode:

```
* Heading 1
body

** Sub-heading 1
body

*** Child 1
body

*** Child 2
body

**** Buried Deep
body

** Sub-heading 2
body

*** Child 1
body
```

When I call `outline-hide-other` with the point on the body of Buried Deep, I get:

```
* Heading 1...
** Sub-heading 1
...
*** Child 2
...
**** Buried Deep
body
...
```

I'm trying to understand, and to ultimately control, where the ellipses appears for invisible text.

I initially thought that a trailing ellipses at the end of a heading was used to denote an invisible body under that heading but no additional headings.

I also initially thought that when the ellipses appeared on a separate line that it was hiding one or more headings in addition to any bodies associated with those headings in the invisible text being denoted by the ellipses.

Both assumptions appear to be wrong, however, so could someone please explain under what conditions the ellipses is placed as trailing text after the heading vs. the conditions under which it is placed on its own line.

Even better would be pointers to any relevant functions and/or variables that can be used to control the placement of these ellipses.

Comment: In Emacs 28.2, the doc-string for `outline-hide-other` states:  "*Hide everything except current body and parent and top-level headings.  This also unhides the top heading-less body, if any.*"  To see what makes it tick, `M-x find-function RET outline-hide-other RET`.

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if it's a bug in ```outline-hide-other```. The documentation for ```outline-flag-region``` in ```outline.el``` appears to imply that the body under a heading technically starts right before the newline at the end of the heading, so perhaps ellipses are supposed to appear on the same line of a heading (trailing at the end of course) whose body is being hidden or whose full subtree is being hidden. Can anyone verify if this is the intended behavior of ellipses under these two scenarios?  If so, then the ellipses by itself under Child 2 violates that principle.

Comment: It would still make sense for ellipses to appear all by themselves on a line if headings are being hidden that do not correspond to a full subtree, as is the case for the ellipses after Sub-heading 1 and after the body of Buried Deep.